# HTML label center aligned getting cropped on both sides

Tags: html, css, angularjs, label, mobile-safari

I'm seeing a bug that is intermittently reproducible only on iPhone Safari (not on any other mobile or desktop browser not even macbook safari). The code looks like:

```
<div style="overflow: auto; height: calc(100% - 55px); background-color: cyan;">
   <ul ...><li..></li> <!-- some ul containing li omitted for brevity-->

   <label class="certainClassname" style="font-size: small; font-style: italic; width: 100%; text-align: center; background-color: yellow">
{{"msg" | translate}}
   </label>
</div>
```

In other style sheet I have:

```
.certainClassname {
    cursor: pointer;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

msg = "PKtest!" for my testing though it usually has another value.

The problem is that this label is getting cropped at the edges when the bug is reproduced as below:

[image]

This bug is only seen on Safari iPhone and none of the other browsers, and seems to only happen the first time that page is loaded, and not later. It could be related to zooming because even the tiniest pinch-to-zoom on iPhone fixes it and the label text (and yellow) expands fully.

Could someone please help me diagnosing this in CSS above? I've tried to fix using each in css of label but none have worked:

```
display: inline;
display: inline-block;
display: block;
padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; 
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto; 
z-index: 999; 
clear: both;
(all these above tested but none fixes this issue seen intermittently and only on iPhone Safari).
```

Comment: Can you provide working code...?

Comment: The above is about as specific code as I'm allowed to share, but I will try to provide details if any specific questions about that label or div tag are posed . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the label is getting cropped might be because of style="overflow: auto; height: calc(100% - 55px)" for div.

div is the parent of label. Therefore label is inheriting its style from its parent. You may consider removing height: calc(100% - 55px) to see if it works

Comment: Seems to work (not sure why), but in what way could this break other things rendered in that div?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to get the idea without reviewing working code. But I tried to run your code, regenerate the bug and here is the possible solution. Let me know, is it something you are looking for?

```css
.certainClassname {
    cursor: pointer;
    word-break: break-all;
    font-size: small; 
    font-style: italic; 
    width: 100%; 
    text-align: center; 
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow: auto; height: calc(100% - 55px); background-color: cyan;">
   <ul ...><li..></li> <!-- some ul containing li omitted for brevity-->

   <label class="certainClassname">
{{"msg" | translate}}
   </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set you label around a div with width: 100% a background-color: yellow

Comment: I tried putting that label inside a <div> </div> but issue still seems to happen.